# Correct media type for swagger spec for downloading zip file

Tags: api, go, swagger, openapi, go-swagger

I am creating an api which allows downloading a zip file, so for this I am looking for correct media type for sending this zip file as response in swagger "2.0" specification.

My current api spec looks like this

```
/config:
  get:
    produces:
      - application/zip
    responses:
        200: # OK
          description: All config files
          schema:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

I have compiled this spec with "go-swagger" and implemented the backend for this, but when try to call this API I get this error

```
http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:20366: applicationZip producer has not yet been implemented
```

In the documentation of swagger I don't see this media type

[Official swagger media types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/media-types/)

So then what should be the correct media type if we want to provide an API to download a zip file.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "application/octet-stream" for implementing api that downloads file as an attachment , and since its Producer is already implemented by default so you won't face this issue.

Comment: Using media type "application/octet-stream" in Swagger will work, but Swagger does not know specifically about zip files, so you will download a file with no extension. After download you will need to add the .zip extension. Other programs like Postman do understand the industry standard "application/zip"

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement this.

The error occurs because of the following generated code:

```golang
func NewSampleAPI(spec *loads.Document) *SampleAPI {
    return &SampleAPI{
    ...
        ApplicationZipProducer: runtime.ProducerFunc(func(w io.Writer, data interface{}) error {
            return errors.NotImplemented("applicationZip producer has not yet been implemented")
        }),
```

So after calling `NewSampleAPI`, you should set `ApplicationZipProducer`:

```golang
api := operations.NewSampleAPI(swaggerSpec)
api.ApplicationZipProducer = func(w io.Writer, data interface{}) error {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any document/example which can provide a guide about how can I implement this Producer? I tried searching but didn't get much.

Comment: Use this as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022866/how-to-implement-new-media-types-in-swagger-backend

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer, using "application/octet-stream"  partially solves the issue, but the browser does not know the file format. I think that his can be improved adding the correct headers to the response, that will tell the browser that the file has a `zip` extension. At least, I can download a file as ZIP and Firefox recognizes it.

```
@Operation(summary = "Downloads a ZIP file)
@GetMapping(value = "/zip", produces="application/octet-stream")
public byte[] start(HttpServletResponse response) {   
        final ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.builder("attachment")
                .filename("MyFile.zip").build();
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());
        return getZipDataAsByteArray();
}
```